# Spring form field errors with Dijit Controls

Tags: spring, dojo

I have a simple form using spring form controls.  I am also using dojoType on the controls.

Ex: `<form:input path="salary" style="width:10em" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"/>`

I am doing some form validation with dojo.  I also added some server side validation with spring.  I was trying to use springs validation to update my dijit fields to be highlighted with errors.  This is what I came up with.  It feels like a hack and I was wondering if anyone has any better solutions.

First on the very bottom of the form I have a hidden span element that lists all the errors returned from spring:hasBindErrors like so:

```
<span id="allErrors" style="visibility:hidden">
     <spring:hasBindErrors name="myForm">
          <c:forEach var="error" items="${errors.allErrors}">
              ${error.field}
          </c:forEach>
     </spring:hasBindErrors>
</span>
```

Then I have a dojo function added onAddLoad that spilts the string of form fields, removes any brackets, and then sets the dijit class to error for the field like this:

```
        dojo.addOnLoad(displayErrors);

    function displayErrors() {
        dojo.forEach(dojo.trim(dojo.byId("allErrors").innerHTML).split(" "), function(value) {
            var newVal = value.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '');
            if (dojo.byId(newVal+'.errors') != 'undefined') {
                dijit.byId(newVal).state = "Error";
                dijit.byId(newVal)._setStateClass();
            }
        });
    }
```

(The reason I am doing a replace is because spring generates id attributes without the brackets but leaves them on the name attribute.  Also the errors are referenced by name not id.)

This works fine but I was just wondering if anyone else came across any solutions similiar to this or if there is an easier way of doing the same thing.

Thanks